# Laravel and TinyMCE

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, laravel-4

I want to install TinyMCE (file manager and imagemanager plugins) within Laravel 4. TinyMCE is located in the folder `/public/assets/plugins/tinu_mce/`. Everything is fine until you start using PHP file in TinyMCE folder. All PHP files get 500 Internal Server Error. Does something need to set up in `.htaccess` or `routes.php`?

Comment: I am using it succesfully. I have the files in my public/js folder which I load with `{{ HTML::script('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}` then initiate tinymce the normal way... Not sure why you are using a php file IN the TinyMCE folder though? It's just a JS library that you load and init()

Comment: filemenager and imagesmenager (tinymce plugin) use php file for upload files and images to server through tinymce

Comment: yes all those files are in my tinymce folder, you just need them for config, you don;t need to access them?

Comment: yes but when browser load tinymce textarea console throw error 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) /assets/plugins/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/lan…ge/index.php?type=im&format=tinymce_3_x&group=tinymce&prefix=imagemanager_` and tinymce editor not show

Comment: maybe check your permissions on those folders? Also can you post the JS where you call TinyMCE ? Does TinyMCE work without the plugins loaded?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a permissions issue. Check your server logs.

Comment: Show us PHP errors log.

Comment: Depending on your use of TinyMCE, you could consider just loading it from cdn and forget the extra hassle.  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Using_CDN